# How to revive The Base Camp?

Tags: discussion, support

I must admit that I haven't been around, but I did try getting to the chat: [The Base Camp](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2291/the-base-camp) and it seems to have been frozen due to lack of activity.

Is there a way to revive this room?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AHem - apologies. I hadn't seen that it was frozen yesterday. Sorted now...

Answer (score 2):

I asked you a question on Base Camp 22 days ago!  Rory can thaw it, I think.

Comment: Yes, I saw that yesterday. I couldn't reply since it was frozen.